# Custom Header not working using $resource

Tags: angularjs

I have created custom header but when i call that service i get Response 401 Unauthorized.Can some point out the issue in the header ?

```
 function getInsuredWebAccount(insuredId) {

        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var web = $resource(webAccountServiceHostName, {}, {
            query: {
                method: 'Get',
                headers: {
                    Authorization:'Bearer c3J1bml0ZTo1OUJFODUwNUIyRjM0OEVGQTI1RTU1RjU4NEVGNUE0'
                }
            }                    
        });
        web.get({ insuredId: insuredId }, function onSuccess(response) {

            var webInfo = response;
            deferred.resolve(response);

        }, function onFailure(response) {
            deferred.reject(response);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

Comment: Did you use developer tools (F12) in your browser of choice, to see if the header was sent?

Comment: If have seen in fiddler header not send

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've added the headers to a query action/method you've created, but then you're calling the standard $resource "get" method.  Try simply:

```
 web.query({ insuredId: insuredId }, function onSuccess(response) { ...
```